# How to add padding to an image using MagickImage in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, imagemagick

I'm trying to write a function that adds padding to an image but I'm not sure on how to do that with ImageMagick.

```
    public bool AddPadding(string filePath)
    {
        // Read from file
        using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(filePath))
        {
            int imageSize;
            int imageX = image.Width;
            int imageY = image.Height;

            if(imageX > imageY)
            {
                imageSize = imageX;
            }
            else
            {
                imageSize = imageY;
            }

            MagickGeometry size = new MagickGeometry(imageSize, imageSize);
            // Probably do more stuff here?




            // Save the result
            image.Write(filePath);
        }
    }
```

What do I need to add so that the image is centered and whitespace is added to both left and right?

Comment: Find the image width (W) and height (H), then use the equivalent of command line -background white -gravity center -extent WxH. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#pad

Comment: Yes I know but I don't know the commands @fmw42

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, you might try posting to https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Extent` method of `MagickImage` for this. Below is an example of how you could do that.

```
public bool AddPadding(string filePath)
{
    // Read from file
    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(filePath))
    {
        int imageSize = Math.Max(image.Width, image.Height);

        // Add padding
        image.Extent(imageSize, imageSize, Gravity.Center, MagickColors.Purple);

        // Save the result
        image.Write(filePath);
    }
}
```

This adds a purple padding so you might want to change the color to a different one instead.